# Racket thinks that a macro application is a function application

Tags: macros, lisp, racket

I am working on a racket project and as part of it, I want to encode certain arithmetic operations as integers. To avoid repeating myself, I have tried to make a couple of macros that automatically generate decoding arms in a `match` statement.

Here are the macros for binary numerical operations:

```lisp
(define-syntax-rule (decode-bin-num-op (op val))
  (with-getters ([floating-point? 60 60]
                 [target 59 57]
                 [in0 56 54]
                 [in1 53 51])
    (op (floating-point? val) (target val) (in0 val) (in1 val))))

(define-syntax decode-bin-num-ops
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ val ((op id) ...))
     (begin (id (decode-bin-num-op (op val))) ...) ]))
```

However, when I try to use the macro as follows:

```lisp
(decode-bin-num-ops instruction ([ADD #b1000]
                                     [SUB #b1001]
                                     [MUL #b1010]
                                     [DIV #b1011]))
```

I get the following errors:

```
Type Checker: could not apply function;
 wrong number of arguments provided
  expected: 4
  given: 1 in: (ADD 8)
```

It seems to think that `(ADD 8)` (and so on for the rest) are function applications, not part of a macro.

Is there a reason this is occuring?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(id (decode-bin-num-op (op val))) ...)`?

Comment: And I think you have an extra set of parens around the arguments to `decode-bin-num-ops` when you call it. Some other odd stuff too...

Comment: Gotta pay attention to the syntax patterns and making sure they match up to how you're calling the macros.

Comment: @Shawn I believe I changed both of these (I've updated the question, but I get the same errors

Comment: @Shawn could part of the issue be a precedence thing, `ADD`, `SUB`, etc. are all struct names

Comment: Think about what `decode-bin-num-ops` expands to... `(begin (#b100 (decode-bin-num-op (ADD instruction))) ....)`. Does that look right?

Comment: @Someone The results of macro expansion gets evaluated so the end result needs to be correct code. Eg. `(ADD 8)` needs to work. `(#b100 ...)` will not work since 4 is not a procedure.

Comment: @Sylwester I am trying to make part of a match statement so I want `#b100` to be the pattern to match

Comment: @Someone That will not work. If you have `(cond (macro-that-expands-to-cond-terms syntax ...))` `cond` will be expanded first and it will faill since the body does not have a valid syntax according to that syntax. The solution is to do the oposite `(macro-that-expands-to-cond syntax ..)` can expand to cond terms and wrap the final result in `cond` as a part of its expansion and then the result is then again macro expanded. If you need additional terms you can add support for your macro to take that as input.